# Adjust PSModulePath via Runspace in .Net code

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm attempting to setup an environment before running some scripts.  This environment is made up of two parts.

- a few modules I want to load beforehand
- a directory full of specific modules that are loadable with a simple 'Import-Module '

I'm ok specifiying the absolute path for the modules that are being 'pre-loaded'.

I'm creating an InitialSessionState object and calling the ImportPSModule and that aspect is working just fine.  Where I'm struggling is getting the module loading path set up.  My goal isn't to *replace* that variable, but to add to it.

I attempted to open the runspace, adjust the env:PSModulePath via the runspace.SessionStateProxy.GetVariable and runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable.  The problem is this requires me to open the runspace.  If I attempt to close it after I'm done I get exceptions when I try to re-open it.  I can leave it open, but I'd prefer not to at that point in my code.

Is there any way for me to manipulate the module loading path without opening up the runspace and setting the variable there?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full path to the module when you call ImportPSModule? I don't have my laptop to test on but I believe this would solve the issue. I'll double check this in a bit.

Comment: To be clear, the ImportPSModule call works, I am specifying the absolute path.  The issue I'm having is in how to add to the env:PSModulePath variable without opening the runspace (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

I just double checked this on my development vm and it does work. You can specify the full path to the module as a parameter to ImportPSModule instead of trying to modify the $PSModulePath variable to point to a custom location.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    iss.ImportPSModule(new[]{@"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Module1\Module1.psd1"});
    using(RunspacePool rsp = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool(iss))
    {
        rsp.Open();
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.RunspacePool = rsp;
        ps.AddScript("get-command -Module 'Module1'");
        foreach(PSObject item in ps.Invoke())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear, I'm able to import modules successfully.  I'm looking for ways to adjust the env:PSModulePath without opening the runspace or being able to open/close/open the runspace (that doesn't appear to be supported).

Comment: You can't reopen a runspace once its been closed. At least not as far as the MSDN documentation reads. You can't adjust the $PSModulePath as the variable isn't created until the runspace is opened. If you are able to specify the direct path to the module to load the modules, why adjust the $PSModulePath? You can just explicitly load them.

Comment: Because I'm setting up an environment to run the scripts in, part of that is pre-loading Modules, part of that is setting up the module path so they can simply import other modules.  I would've liked to open it up, add it in, close it, hand it off to other parts of the code, and then have them open it up when they're ready.  I ended up just handing it around already opened.