# Appending to $PSModulePath from C# via API

Tags: .net, powershell

When using C#/.Net to execute a PowerShell script, I'd like to **add** a path to $PSModulePath without overwriting the default $PSModulePath.

I've figured out how to set $PSModulePath to a value of my choosing using InitialSessionState.EnvironmentVariables. However, this approach is **not desirable** as it *replaces* the default $PSModulePath instead of *appending* to it.

```
var state= InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
state.EnvironmentVariables.Add(new SessionStateVariableEntry("PSModulePath", myModuleLoadPath, "PowerShell Module Search Locations"));
var runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialState);

using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    powershell
        .AddScript(script)
        .Invoke();
}
```

Is there a way to programmatically use a .Net API **append** to $PSModulePath?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, the environment variable `PSModulePath` isn't populated with the default `PSModulePath` until the `Runspace` is open. Setting `PSModulePath` by on an `InitialSessionState` which is passed to `RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()` suppresses this auto-population.

To manipulate the default `PSModulePath`, **wait until the relevant `Runspace` is open**, then get/set the variable, as desired, using `SessionStateProxy.GetVariable()`/`SetVariable()`.

```
using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    runspace.Open();

    var proxy = runspace.SessionStateProxy;
    var psModulePath = proxy.GetVariable("env:PSModulePath");
    proxy.SetVariable("env:PSModulePath", $"{psModulePath};{extraPathToAppend}");

    using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;

        powershell
            .AddScript(script)
            .Invoke();
    }
}
```

The same effect can be achieved by accessing the current `PowerShell` instance's `Runspace` property. This approach eliminates the need to explicitly create and open a `Runspace` instance.

```
using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    var proxy = powershell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy;
    var psModulePath = proxy.GetVariable("env:PSModulePath");
    proxy.SetVariable("env:PSModulePath", $"{psModulePath};{extraPathToAppend}");

    powershell
        .AddScript(script)
        .Invoke();

}
```

Thanks to question [Adjust PSModulePath via Runspace in .Net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999520/adjust-psmodulepath-via-runspace-in-net-code) for helping me figure this out!